# Spring boot logging with log4j - how do I ENABLE spring boot log entries?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, spring-boot

I configured spring boot to use log4j with these lines in pom.xml:

```
    <!-- use log4j instead of logback (spring boots own logging) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I stopped spring from logging at debug level to console by configuring my log4j.xml like that:

```
<root>
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
</root>
```

My question is what do I have to put into log4j.xml to get to see log messages from spring boot? This was not working for example (addition to log4j.xml):

```
<category name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="trace" />
</category>
```

What is the correct path or the correct method to get spring boot to log again using log4j?

Comment: what's wrong with logback? logback is great! :) Whatever you chose make sure to use Slf4j as well!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should have set the Error level to Info Level if you want to standard Spring output.

From the Log4J quick start site https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

> This rule is at the heart of log4j. It assumes that levels are
>   ordered. For the standard levels, we have DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR
>   < FATAL

So root should probably look like this

```xml
<root>
    <level value="Info" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's `<logger>` not `<category>`. Note that Spring Boot also saves you from having to remember that by making log levels configurable in application.properties.

Comment: So spring boot will automatically scan for a file `application.properties` on classpath and set the loglevel, if it finds a directive within that file? Even in Junit Environment?

Comment: Of course it only works if you use a `SpringApplication` (e.g. in unit test with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`).